# Why does this program produce a stack overflow error?

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
  Test t = new Test();
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t1 = new Test();
  }
}
```

Comment: because Test instantiates Test() !

Answer (score 4):

Your code has no constructor, this is what the compiler does -

```
public class Test {
  Test t; // <-- initializer copied to every constructor body, even the default.
  public Test() { // <-- compiler adds default constructor,
    super();
    t = new Test(); //<-- infinite recursion.
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t1 = new Test(); // <-- invokes default constructor
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because whenever new object of `Test` is created it will again create a object `t` while will again initialize... and this continues

```
public class Test {
    Test t = new Test(); //-> recursive instantiation
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t1 = new Test();
    }
}
```

Try removing `Test t = new Test();` or make it static `static Test t = new Test();` and it should fix your issue.

```
public class Test {
    static Test t = new Test(); //or remove it
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t1 = new Test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this row:

```
Test t = new Test();
```

will generate infinite recursive instantiation.